# Pure-javascript longpolling for chat

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, chat, long-polling

So I have started a project, where I want to make an online ajax chat, but I do NOT want to use jQuery JSON, COMET and so on. I am looking for pure javascript, no libraries no framework.

Good news is that I have already made the chat and it is working fine. Why do i make this post? Because I simply cannot find any pure javascript solution for long-polling. Currently I am using the setInterval method to "ask" the database to send whatever is in the database. now, how do I execute my ajax request whenever I get a response? (Long-polling).

please bear in mind that I am not looking for a jQuery solution or what have you.. I am using pure JavaScript and PHP. No framework or library.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Here is a jQuery example, you just need to un-jQuery it: http://stackoverflow.com/a/333884/600135

Comment: I have in fact checked that thread out. But problem is that I cannot "un-jQuery" it, that is why I was asking for a pure JS solution :-)

You see, the "success:" part of jQuery is probably what I am looking for. But I have no idea what that looks like without jQuery

Comment: Still need some answers if people have got them.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8567114/how-to-make-an-ajax-call-without-jquery

Comment: Unless i am mistaken, you link to ajax with pure javascript. And i already have that. I need the long-polling part.

Comment: There's a good example of a pure PHP/Javascript (no jQuery) example of a long polling chat application in this book: http://www.packtpub.com/ajax-and-php-building-responsive-web-applications/book

Answer (score 0):

i believe this is relatively close to what your looking for - referencing a vanilla js ajax tutorial on nettuts plus:

```
load('test.txt', function(xhr) { 
    document.getElementById('container').innerHTML = xhr.responseText;  
    // you would obviously custom tailor this peice to utilize your specific data
});  

function load(url, callback) {  
    var xhr;  

    if(typeof XMLHttpRequest !== 'undefined') xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();  
    else {  
        var versions = ["MSXML2.XmlHttp.5.0",   
                        "MSXML2.XmlHttp.4.0",  
                        "MSXML2.XmlHttp.3.0",   
                        "MSXML2.XmlHttp.2.0",  
                        "Microsoft.XmlHttp"]  

         for(var i = 0, len = versions.length; i < len; i++) {  
            try {  
                xhr = new ActiveXObject(versions[i]);  
                break;  
            }  
            catch(e){}  
         } // end for  
    }  

    xhr.onreadystatechange = ensureReadiness;  

    function ensureReadiness() {  
        if(xhr.readyState < 4) {  
            return;  
        }  

        if(xhr.status !== 200) {  
            return;  
        }  

        // all is well    
        if(xhr.readyState === 4) {  
            callback(xhr);  
        }             
    }  

    xhr.open('GET', url, true);  
    xhr.send('');  
}
```

and you could build your "success" handlers into the 'ensure readiness'  based on the return values

[heres a link to the nettuts tutorial](http://net.tutsplus.com/articles/news/how-to-make-ajax-requests-with-raw-javascript/)

[and another to the MDN ajax API docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/AJAX)

Comment: one of the downsides in this method is the object referenced varies whether you are using ie or a real web browser... the ActiveXObject  vs XMLHttpRequest - another reason i cant wait for the end of the browser wars and the day we stop spoon feeding ie back version users

Comment: While this is a good tutorial, it doesn't really cover my needs, since i basically already have written what this guy is teaching. Just need the long polling part. The part that prevents my server from getting too much trafic. I am using a setInterval function to keep asking if there is anything in the database. but long-polling should keep the connection open untill the database refreshes